# Filehelpers - Complex record layout assistance

Tags: edi, filehelpers

We are attempting to use filehelpers for some file interface projects specifically dealing with EDI. The sample definition below makes use of the EDI 858 Specification. Like most interface specs, each vendor has their own flavor. You can find a sample 858 EDI spec [here](http://www.tsilogistics.com/858%20-%204010%20%28Shipment%20Information%29_Draft_based_on_Mead_Johnsont.pdf)

Our Vendor has their own flavor; this is the sample record definition we are currently using from before conversion:

```
H1_Record_type      As String ' * 8  EDI858FF
H2_TRANS_DATE       As String ' * 8 yyyyMMdd
H3_Trans_type       As String ' * 2 00 = New, 01 = Cancel Carrier, 03 = Delete, 04 = Change
H4_Pay_type         As String ' * 2 PP = Prepaid, CC = Collect, TP = Third Party (our default is PP)
H5_Load             As String ' * 30 Authorization
H6_Load_Ready_date  As String ' * 12 yyyyMMddHHmm
H7_Commodity        As String ' * 10
H8_Customer_HQ_ID   As String ' * 20 hard coded '0000000001'
H9_Customer         As String
H10_Mill_ID         As String ' * 20 Shipping Perdue Location or Destination Perdue Location
H11_Tender_Method   As String ' * 10 blank for now
H12_Carrier_ID      As String ' * 10 blank for now
H13_Weight          As String ' * 7 estimated total load weight
H14_Weight_Qualifier As String ' * 2 blank for now
H15_Total_Miles     As String ' * 7 zero for now
H16_Total_quantity  As String ' * 7 blank for now
H17_Weight_Unit     As String ' * 1 L = pounds, K = Kilograms, L=default
H18_REF             As String ' * 3 REF
            HR1_Ref_qualifier   As String ' * 3 CO = Deliv Dest ref., P8 = Deliv Orig Ref.
            HR2_Ref_value       As String ' * 80
H19_END_REF                 As String ' * 7 END REF
H20_SPEC_INSTRUCTION        As String ' * 16 SPEC INSTRUCTION
            HS1_Qualifier           As String ' * 3  1 = Credit Hold, 7T = Export Order, HM = Hazmat, L = Load ready for pickup
                                ' PTS = Tarp, RO = Hot Load, TAR = Full Tarp, WTV = Weight Verification, DDN = Driver needs TWIC
                                ' PR = Prohibited
H21_END_SPEC                As String ' * 20 END SPEC INSTRUCTION
H22_NOTE                    As String ' * 4 NOTE
             HN1_Note_Qualifier      As String ' * 3 SPH = Special Handling, PRI = Load Priority, DEL = Transit Days
            HN2_Note                As String ' * 80
H23_END_NOTE                As String ' * 8 END NOTE
H24_EQUIPMENT               As String ' * 9 EQUIPMENT
H25_END                     As String ' * 13 END EQUIPMENT
H26_LOAD_CONTACT            As String ' * 12 LOAD CONTACT
             LC1_Contact_Name        As String ' * 60
             LC2_Contact_type        As String ' * 2  EM= E-mail, FX = Fax, TE = Telephone
             LC3_Contact_Data        As String ' * 80
H27_END_LOAD_CONTACT        As String ' * 16 END LOAD CONTACT
H28_STOP                    As String ' * 4 STOP  There will always be 2 - CL and CU
    S1_Stop_Number          As String ' * 2
    S2_Stop_Reason          As String ' * 2 CL = Complete Load, CU = Complete Unload (one of each required for every load)
    S3_LOCATION             As String ' * 8 LOCATION
        SL1_Location_ID     As String ' * 20
        SL2_Location_Name   As String ' * 60
        SL3_Location_Add1   As String ' * 55
        SL4_Location_Add2   As String ' * 55
        SL5_Location_City   As String ' * 30
        SL6_Location_State  As String ' * 2
        SL7_Location_Zip    As String ' * 10 (use only 5 digits)
        SL8_Location_Country As String ' * 3 USA, CAN, MEX
    S4_END_LOCATION         As String ' * 12 END LOCATION
    S5_STOP_DATE            As String ' * 9 STOP DATE
        SD1_Date_Qualifier  As String ' * 3 37 = No earlier than, 38 = No later than, 10 = Expected arrival time, 35 = Actual arrival
                                ' 11 = Actual departure
        SD2_Date_Time       As String ' * 12  yyyyMMddHHmm
    S6_END_STOP_DATE        As String ' * 13 END STOP DATE
    S7_STOP_REF             As String ' * 8 STOP REF
        SR1_Reference_Qualifier As String ' 3 72 = Transit Time, DK = Dock Number, OQ = Order Number
        SR2_Reference_Value As String ' * 80
    S8_END_STOP_REF         As String ' * 12 END STOP REF
H29_END_STOP                As String ' * 8 END STOP
H30_ORDER                   As String ' * 5 ORDER
    O1_Order_Number         As String ' * 80
H31_END_ORDER               As String ' * 9 END ORDER
```

this is a sample message it would normally be in one long line:

> EDI858FF~20140611~04~PP~1266010982~201406060700~CANOLA
>   ML~0000000001~Business Name~RICHLAND~~~60000~~0~~L~REF~SA~Customer
>   Name~END REF~STOP~01~CL~LOCATION~RICHLAND~~~~~~~~END LOCATION~STOP
>   DATE~37~201406060000~END STOP DATE~STOP REF~OQ~5568~END STOP REF~END
>   STOP~STOP~02~CU~LOCATION~261450~~~~~~~~END LOCATION~STOP
>   DATE~37~201406060000~END STOP DATE~STOP REF~OQ~5568~END STOP REF~END
>   STOP~ORDER~5568~END ORDER

I really think this may be too complex of a task for Filehelpers, but I wanted to put it out there to the community to see if you all could help.

As you can see the file is mostly tilde delimited, however certain fields in the definition also act as delimiters. For instance REF or STOP both contain additional information that could be many records deep. You could have multiple STOP definitions 1 to 999 location records. I am really really thinking that this is just too much for Filehelpers...

If you were to attempt this configuration for filehelpers, where would you start and how would you handle all the child fields?

Comment: Are you looking to produce valid EDI with FileHelpers?  Your EDI sample is incomplete.  There are three delimiters in an ANSI X12 file:  the segment terminator (which might be a CR or LF, can't tell from your sample), the element delimiter (in your case the tilde) and the Sub-element separator (defined in the ISA envelope segment missing from your sample).  You could probably use filehelpers, but it would be a ton of code, and a lot of hassle.  EDIDev.com has libraries that would help you here, or a commercial translator would also be wise (for TP management and FA reconciliation)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I dont have access to the actual 858 spec for the vendor we use. Only the file spec that they are expecting us to feed into their system which is what I provided. Ill take a look at the libraries and see if we can incorporate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileHelpers is not the ideal tool for such a complex format. These are the reasons:

1. Not have enough flexibility with regard to identifying and reporting errors.
2. Difficulties with escaped characters (e.g., when a tilde is within a field and needs to be escaped) I'm not familiar enough with the EDI format to know if this is likely to be an issue.
3. The master/detail tools provided by FileHelpers are insufficient

For (1), you don't mention whether you are importing or exporting EDI, or both. If you are only exporting EDI, error reporting would not be necessary.

For (2), you *could* work around the escaping problems by providing your [own custom converters](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_advanced.html) for the problem fields, but you might find every single field has a custom converter.

For (3), There are two ways of handling master/detail records with FileHelpers, but neither of them are likely to cover your requirements without some serious hacking

One way would be [to use the `MasterDetailEngine`](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_masterdetail.html), but this only supports one detail type and only one level of nesting, so you would have to find workarounds for both of these.

Another way would be to use the [to use the `MultiRecordEngine`](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_multirecords.html). However, it would treat each row as an unrelated record and the hierarchy (that is, which S record belongs to which H record) would be hard to determine.

Comment: yea, we decided that filehelpers wasnt quite up to the task for this one. I am going to close the question. Thank you for your input. what makes it even harder is that the file isnt a true EDI file, its a file layout that is then converted to EDI by PI/SAP...we have gone another way since in this case filehelpers just can t be used.